# No Individual User Accounts auth option in ASP.NET Core Web API template despite VS 2017 Preview

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I want to set Individual User Accounts auth option in ASP.NET Core Web API template as suggested at this link using VS 2017 Preview:

[No Individual User Accounts auth option in ASP.NET Core Web API template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41061926/no-individual-user-accounts-auth-option-in-asp-net-core-web-api-template)

But when I tried, this option is not available for that. it is shown as this:
[VS Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qui4d.png)
How did this person find this feature please?

Comment: Did you make sure that drop down list does not have other option?

Comment: @wannadream Yes of course I did

Comment: It looks like it's a pending issue: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/2875, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734194/local-user-account-store-for-web-api-in-asp-net-core-2-0